# Set post to unpublished after one week depending on condition

Tags: custom-field, wp-cron, cron

I have a post type with a custom field checkbox. If this checkbox is checked and the post is published, I want to unpublish when one week has passed since last modified date.

How would I go about doing this? Do I need to run a cron?

In pseudocode:

```
if mycheckbox is 1 && post is published && last modified date > one week 
    unpublish post
```

(Edit) I think I got something going here now. The function does more or less what it's suppose to. I just have to wait an hour and see if the cron job works aswell.

```
// Unpublish fixed occurences one week after last modified date, run this function in a cron once daily
function xxx_occurences_unpublish_posts(){
    global $wpdb;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'private_occurrences',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'occurrence_fixed',
                'value' => 1,
                'compare' => '=='
            )
        ),
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
            'after' => '1 week ago'
            )
            array(
            'column' => 'post_modified_gmt',
            'after' => '1 week ago',
            )
         ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $posts = $query->get_posts();

    foreach( $posts as $post) {

      $post_to_be_updated = array(
          'ID' => $post->ID,
          'post_status' => 'Private',
      );

      wp_update_post( $post_to_be_updated );
    }
}

// Set up cron to run above unpublish function once daily
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled('xxx_cron_unpublish_occurrences') ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'xxx_cron_unpublish_occurrences' ); // hourly, daily and twicedaily
}
add_action( 'xxx_cron_unpublish_occurrences', 'xxx_occurences_unpublish_posts' );
```

Comment: Be sure to post your edit as an answer if your code works :-)